# Upload image to firebase and save url in sqlite DJango

Tags: python, django, firebase

suddenly someone can guide me.
I made an application, people have a normal profile, with a series of fields that can modify the profile photo, locally it works perfectly, however, when deploying it in heroku (free account) it is not possible because heroku in its free version does not handle dynamic files, or at least that is what I understood, so I want to save the images in firebase and only the urls in the database. Anyone have any idea how I can do this?
Thank you very much for your answers

This is the code currently

**views.py**

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UEditF(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                            instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid() and extended_profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            extended_profile_form.save()
            return redirect('/polls/perfil')
    else:
        form = UEditF(instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'extended_profile_form':extended_profile_form
    }
    form.fields['password'].help_text = 'Para cambiar la contraseña has clic en el menú superior derecho "Cambiar contraseña"'
    return render(request, 'registration/edit_profile.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UEditF(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'), label='Fecha de nacimiento')
    photo = forms.ImageField(label="Foto de perfil")
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField('Fecha de nacimiento', default=date.today)
    photo = models.ImageField('Foto de perfil', upload_to='media/',
                              max_length=200, default='default.png')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Follow these steps:**

1. Add Cloudinary Addon to your Heroku app.
2. Click on cloudinary and install it.
3. Then click on Cloudinary addon.
4. From this dashboard you will be able to see your credentials
   to connect with.

**5) Then go to your project:**

```
IN your terminal type these commands:

pip install django-cloudinary-storage
    
pip install cloudinary
    
pip install Pillow
```

**6) In your settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',   
       'cloudinary_storage',
       'cloudinary',
        ]

CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
             'CLOUD_NAME': 'your_cloud_name',
             'API_KEY': 'your_api_key',
             'API_SECRET': 'your_api_secret'
            }

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  # or any prefix you choose
 
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE='cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'
```

**7) In models.py:**

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
             name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
             image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', 
             blank=True)
```

**8) Now, in order to put this image into your template, you can just type:**

```
 <img src="{{ test_model_instance.image.url }}" alt="{{ 
    test_model_instance.image.name }}">
```

**9) requirements.txt:**

```
...
cloudinary==1.17.0
django-cloudinary-storage==0.2.3
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly and I didn't have to do much. Thank you very much!