# Why do I get 404 error when trying to GET image from heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, rest

So I have deployed my Django project via heroku. I'm testing my api calls, but getting error when fetching images.
On request, I was able to get this data :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "source": 2,
    "category": [
        1,
        4
    ],
    "key_line": "blabla",
    "footnote": "",
    "created_at": "2021-07-19",
    "image": "https://bookcake.herokuapp.com/api/cake/media/None/rlvdmseoghk.jpg",
}
```

Now the problem is the `image` field. All other data show up fine in the front-end, but the image doesn't. As well, nothing shows up when I click on that link. What could be the problem? 
 
 Here's my settings.py file for your information, but I don't see any problem with it.

```
...
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Comment: add your html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does not have a persistent file system, which means that it cannot serve Media files.

To serve Media files you'll need to host the files elsewhere like AWS-s3...

Heroku provide [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Rbrand&utm_content=482515151161&utm_term=cloudinary&gclid=Cj0KCQjwxdSHBhCdARIsAG6zhlUhVdqtUYmn-IqD_r77MIK7qZBS4bIS5ZnKcXBqUUgFEVoxIrbJYkUaAsfPEALw_wcB) Addon which is provide up to 10GB free storage and their Connection is very simple.

[HOW TO CONNECT CLOUDINARY STORAGE IN DJANGO PROJECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63968876/14131913) follow this steps..